# Prevent typed characters from being displayed (like disabling "echo" attribute in termios)

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal, termios

I'm writing a bash script in which I read single characters from the input. I do so using `read -n 1 -s`. `-n 1` is to read only a single character; `-s` is "silent" mode, in which the typed characters won't be visible.

The problem is, that when the currently executed command isn't `read` (whenever some other commands in the bash script are being executed), the character gets displayed in the terminal.

This is the normal behaviour of a program in the terminal. To disable this, one normally disables the echo mode, for example using the termios library.

How can I achieve this in a bash script?

I prefer solutions in pure bash / Unix commands (without other scripting languages like python, perl etc.).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
stty -echo
# Anything they type won't output here
stty echo
# Now it will
```